# Metal kernel writes random numbers into MTLBuffer if it is indexed with a variable - data hazard?

Tags: ios, iphone, metal

I am trying to implement a high dynamic range algorithm on the GPU for which i need to calculate a histogram. The metal code looks like this so far:

```
kernel void
hist(texture2d_array<half, access::read> inArray [[texture(0)]],
        device float *t [[buffer(0)]], // ignore this
        volatile device uint *histogram [[buffer(1)]],
        uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]){

int4 Y_ldr;
uint redChannel;

for(uint i = 0; i < inArray.get_array_size(); i++){
    Y_ldr = int4(inArray.read(gid, i, 0) * 255);
    redChannel = Y_ldr.r;
    histogram[redChannel]++;
}
```

}

The Kernel fills half of the histogram (256 entries) with huge numbers, the other half is null (initial values).
Instead, when I write

```
histogram[0] = 1; // just a number
histogram[0] = redChannel; // OR this
```

I get the correct number at position 0 in both cases. Using atomic_uint doesn't help, so does the threadgroup barrier.
Trying

```
  histogram[0]++;
```

reveals that metal does not handle data hazards automatically, but the numbers are small, i.e. like 12000.
So, what is causing the trouble that

1. I get unreasonable numbers
2. exactly half of the array ist missed out?

If you need to know, how the pipeline state is set up, see here:

```
var threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1)
var threadgroups = MTLSizeMake(pictures!.width/threadGroupCount.width, pictures!.height/threadGroupCount.height, 1)
computeCommandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(hist!)
computeCommandEncoder.setTexture(pictures, atIndex: 0)
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(exposure_times, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
computeCommandEncoder.setBuffer(histogram, offset: 0, atIndex: 1) // <-- this is important!!!CommandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
```

Comment: Sitting all on this issue, I found following out: 

histogram[0] = 55; --> cpu reads 55 at position 0,
histogram[1] = 55; ---> cpu read 4567856348569 at position 0,
histogram[2] = 55; ---> cpu reads 55 at position 1,

I think that the cpu and gpu interpret the length of an int/uint differently.

Answer (score 3):

jesus -.- 
The iPad CPU interprets UInt as a 64bit number (8 bytes). To the GPU, Int implicates 32bit (4 bytes). When the pointer is set at position [1], the CPU interprets this position a the upper 4 bytes of the array entry [0]. That causes the insanely huge numbers.
To solve this issue, I have to set up the histogram to be [UInt32] on the CPU side.

Comment: You made my day! So difficult to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Nice to hear! To avoid any of such problems, import Metalkit. It adds the metal data types for usage on the host side (uint, float4 etc...). Do not use Swift data types. Else, if you want to copy a value to the GPU, you can cast it with `myValue = uint(x)`.

Comment: This is because Metal doesn't support 8-bit numbers. You'll get similar issues passing Double to Float.